# Is there some kind of find method on Arrays that returns [item | undefined] rather than item | undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is some code from I project I am working in:

```
    const profile = userdataDocs
        .filter(isValidUserdataDocument)
        .find((document: ICouchDBDocumentDoc) => document._id === profileId);

    if (profile) {
        return {
            id: hashSensitive(profile._id, environment),
            type: profile.type,
            creationDate: profile.creationDate,
            updatedDate: profile.updatedDate,
            entityVersion: profile.entityVersion,
        };
    }
```

Here is how I would like to have my code look:

```
    return userdataDocs
        .filter(isValidUserdataDocument)
        .filter((document: ICouchDBDocumentDoc) => document._id === profileId)
        .map((profile: ICouchDBDocumentDoc) => ({
            id: hashSensitive(profile._id, environment),
            type: profile.type,
            creationDate: profile.creationDate,
            updatedDate: profile.updatedDate,
            entityVersion: profile.entityVersion,
        }))
        .slice(0, 1);
```

But I get feedback from the rest of my team that I should not use filter because it will continue searching after having found an item. Premature optimization in mind, but still a pretty valid and popular opinion.

Is there some other array method (or altogether different solution) that I can use to write code the way I want, with 'pipes', without getting the performance penalty of moving from find to filter?

Also let me know if I am an idiot and should let go of the pipe dream (pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

Let me start that I like the first solution. In my opinion, it looks good.

But if you are really desperate for a solution that fulfills your pipe dream

```
    const array = [10, 20, 30];

    function singleMapFind(args, fn) {
        const currentArray = args[2];
        const duplicate = [...currentArray];
        currentArray.splice(1, currentArray.length - 1);
        return duplicate.find(fn);
    }

    const modified = array.map((...args) => singleMapFind(args, (e) => e > 20));
```

I would never use it though. Wish you luck with the PR.